# MVC and asynchronous partials

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I have an application that has several(4-7) WebService requests to external endpoints. It takes 2-5s to load each request. Requests are loaded using ajax and displayed on the page as partial views.

The problem is that each subsequent request waits for the previous one to be completed before it starts.

Ajax allows me to display them as they are loaded without freezing the page, however is it at all possible for all of the requests to be loaded asynchronously? Can all partial views be loaded at the same time?

Comment: Ajax itself is asynchronous. What else are you looking for? Can you show some code from Views/Controllers?

Comment: Ajax sends asynchronous requests to the server, but server can only process them sequentially.

Comment: In that case you can make controllers async that are returning partial views and have long running non-cpu bound processes. and that in your case is external webservices.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it would be a lot clearer with some code.  *Especially* in light of your self-answer so we can see what's talking to your answer's server code.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to development environment, my code will not replicate the problem in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it resolved.
I am now starting all of the services the moment application starts and I store them in the static class:

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Task<Room>> informationHolder = 
        new Dictionary<string, Task<Room>>();
}
public ActionResult Index(){
    foreach (var room in roomList)
    {
        int index = roomList.IndexOf(room);
        Settings.informationHolder.Add(
            roomList[index].Email, 
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => loadRoomData(roomList[index].Email)));
        }
    }
```

After this, I simply await for the task to be finished in my partial views:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> _RoomMeetings(string roomEmail)
{
    var room = 
        await Settings.informationHolder.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key == roomEmail).Value;
}
```

Bottleneck is still possible, but application loads 2x faster.